# VBScript IE automation - Pressing "Ok" on a Confirm Popup

Tags: vbscript

I'm automating a web application. I can currently get the webpage to enter some info into a form and press a Submit button. However, the page requires a confirmation prior to submit the form. It calls the confirm() function which pops-up a small window with Ok or Cancel. I want to automate the clicking of 'Ok'.

It doesn’t work with SendKeys, because when the confirm() popup function is called, the Wscript seems to pause & wait for the confirmation (Ok or Cancel) before continuing.

My code is attached below:

```
 Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 objIE.Visible = True
 objIE.Navigate "www.abc.com"
 Do While objIE.Busy Or (objIE.READYSTATE <> 4)
     Wscript.Sleep 100
 Loop

 objIE.Document.all(73).value = "Testing…" 'this is the form input
 objIE.Document.all(106).click  'this is the submit button

 'Confirm box will come up here & I want to press 'Ok'

 ***'Something in here to press the popup Ok button???***
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you look at this differently and run a http post request directly to the action target of the form?

Comment: Or just replace the confirm function with your own always returning true function, like `objIE.Window.Eval "window.confirm = function(){ return true; };"`?

Answer (score 1):

Simple but not totally fail proof solution: Just before the click, startup a new VBScript file through the WSH with a 1 second wait and a `sendkey "{ENTER}"` action in it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is certainly not fail proof either.

Can you click the submit button using `SendKeys` instead of `objIE.Document.all(106).click`?

If so, then you could try sending two keys in a row, i.e. `SendKeys "{ENTER}{ENTER}"` (or whatever two keys are required in each case).

If not, then you could try sending `SendKeys "{ENTER}"` *before* clicking the submit button using `objIE.Document.all(106).click` (after making sure that no field is selected). In some cases, the sent key is kept in memory until such time where it is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`objIE.Document.all.item("106").click`

It find the item and click it.